# Positive semi definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

Let $C \in M_n(\mathbb R) $. We know that $C^T C$ is positive semi definite and symmetric. Let $D\in M_n(\mathbb R)$, such that $D^2 = C^TC$. Show that $\exists P \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ with $P^{-1} = P^T$, such that $C = PD$

Comment: A classic way of doing it is by using topological properties of $ S_n^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ , $ S_n^+(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ O_n(\mathbb{R}) $, and the polar decomposition for invertible matrices.

Comment: @FreeSalad I considered the invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1} C^TC Q = D $ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $r$ number of  $1$s down the diagonal. Then the first $r$ columns of $Q$ is orthogonal. Extend this to a orthogonal basis $B$ for $\mathbb R^n$  Let $P_c$ be the matrix whose colums are $B$. Then $P_c^T (CQ) = D$ 

Not sure why $P_c^T (CQ) = D$ is true thou.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I don't know of a direct way of proving this, but if you've done any topology, you could start by showing that there's a unique polar decomposition $ C = PD $ for $ \det C \not = 0 $.